# Using the Braintree drop-in UI to select the payment method for recurring billing -- or: finding the payment method of a paymentMethodNonce

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, braintree

I'm building a simple payment system using Braintree payments, PHP and JavaScript. I'm using Braintree's Drop-in UI, and would like to create subscriptions (i.e. recurring billing).

For this, I'm using:

```php
// $_customer is a Braintree_Customer object; a customer stored in the Vault
$subscription_create = Braintree_Subscription::create([
  'id' => $_customer->id,
  'planId' => 'some_package',
  'paymentMethodToken' => $_customer->defaultPaymentMethod()->token
]);
```

This works fine, and creates a subscription using the customer's 'default payment method'. However, I don't see any way for the customer to change his default payment method. There does not seem to be an option for this in the drop-in UI.

Does this mean I cannot use the drop-in UI for recurring billing? Should I write my own UI to allow customers to change their default payment method?

---

[There is a way](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/payment-methods#make-default) to make a payment method the default one. I could use that one, however, I only receive a paymentMethodNonce from the client. How do I find the paymentMethod linked to that nonce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, you can always [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You don't need a special method for this, you can [pass the nonce directly to `Braintree_PaymentMethod::create`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/payment-methods#create):

```
$result = Braintree_PaymentMethod::create(array(
    'customerId' => '12345',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonce-from-the-client'
));
```

Comment: It would very good if this was mentioned in developer documentation of create subscription by drop-in for BrainTree. Anyway this answer came up after an hour later when i research.